# Variable not updating in addeventlistener after value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I have a variable set to `false`. I also have a `addEventListener` so when I click on the button, it should show me the variable's value (true or false).

I have another button that changes the variable's value to `true`. So when I press that button to change it to true, and then I check the variable's value with the `addEventListener` button, it should reflect as true. The problem is that it doesn't.

It should alert that the status is **true** after pressing the "Set Status" button. Why is the value not changing?

here is the code:

```
<button id="button">Set Status</button>
<br>
<button id="check-status">Check Status</button>

<script>
var status = false;

document.getElementById('check-status').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(status === false) {
        alert('The status is false');
    } else {
        alert('The status is true');
    }
});

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function fun() {
    setStatusTrue();
}

function setStatusTrue() {
    var status = true;
}
</script>
```

Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/xpLuh0ew/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up the scope of the variable. To set the `status` variable that is outside the function scope use:

```
function setStatusTrue() {
    status = true;
}
```

You can read more about scopes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)